# Can't connect to SQL Server with python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to access a SQL Server database that I will edit with Python. For this I've installed SQL Server with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Using the following code I can access to my database:

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
                      'Server=SERG-PC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=Kirin;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

It works when I launch it from my laptop (with SQL Server), however it doesn't when I do it from another computer. An error occurs saying that the connection is prohibited or there is no such a server. Obviously, other people also had this problem. I checked all the possible discussions related to this error. I have enabled TCP protocol with SQL Server Configuration and added sqlserver.exe into the inbound rules of my firewall. However it didn't help. So, I have the following questions:

1. Server='' parameter needs either my host name or my ip address. It works when I enter the host name but it doesn't when I enter my ip (where SQL Server is installed).
2. Why the hostname works on my laptop (with SQL Server) but it doesn't work on another laptop when I'm trying to connect to my laptop?
3. How to know the proper ip+port and how to use them to connect from any computer to my laptop with the SQL Server?

Comment: There is nothing to handle the request from one machine to another. I believe this problem is typically solved with a domain controller that resolves hostnames to their address.

Comment: I think you need to create a username and password to access, also check that the database and the user have permissions to access remotely, then check if from the other machine you have connected to port 1433 (telnet IP_Server_DATABASE 1433)  using the domain or by ip

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server Express Edition is not exposed on the network.

Follow the instructions here: [Lesson 2: Connecting from Another Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15) to enable remote access to your SQL Server instance.